# Algorithms/methods to compile forum discussions into categorized articles or information?

Tags: java, data-mining, text-mining

I'm designing and coding a knowledge based community sharing system (forum, Q&A, article sharing between students, professors and experts) in Java, for the web.

I need to use some data mining/text processing techniques/algorithms to analyse the discussions between experts and students (discussions are categorized using tags) and create proper notes and compilations on specific similar topics.

I'm not an expert regarding such algorithms or tools available. It'd be great if anyone can provide me with some pointers or explain how I can proceed with this problem.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For categorization of articles you can use LSA (Latent Semantic Analysis) technique .

You can check these tools for text processing.

1. [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/index.html) : Tool kit for processing text.
2. [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) : Text mining
3. [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) : Powerful text search tool

Answer (score 0):

Start reading up on Text Mining. There is no general answer to your question because it is not precise enough. You must be more precise about your aims, then people can suggest methods for these. Your "analyze" is way too broad. Counting the number of words is "analyzing", too!

So: what do you want to recognize, group or predict?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Basically I want the program to make summaries of discussions similar to each other (sharing maximum tags, and similar question/subject) which a person can read later.

For example, suppose a question recieves 20-25 answers, long and short, and the asker selects the best answer, maybe rates others too. The algorithm needs to select a set of similar questions (say 2/3) and generate a summary in a basic Question-(Answer+debates/challenges) format.